# query not searching the correct table

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa

Hi guys i am trying to search a table called address i exsists and i can add data to it etc

however when i come to running a query for it i get the following error

```
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u FROM ADDRESS U WHERE u.details LIKE :search]. 
[14, 21] The abstract schema type 'ADDRESS' is unknown.
[30, 39] The state field path 'u.details' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

this is the query i am trying to run

```
public List<User> advancedSearch(String searchString, String criteria, String Searchcountry) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM ADDRESS U WHERE "
            + "u.details "  + "LIKE :search");
    q.setParameter("search", "%" + searchString + "%");
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

the table has the columns ID, COUNTRY, DETAILS and POSTCODE

Why can i not search from this table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table names and alias names are case sensitive. Is your table name really all upper case `ADDRESS`?

Your alias is `U`, but you try to reference details column by `u`.

Also, you probably meant `SELECT u.*`, not `SELECT u`.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT u FROM ADDRESS U`, doesn't look right, change to `select *` or make alias `u`